# Resistor vs wire in Arduino, breadboard

Tags: arduino, resistors, breadboard

I was trying out different tutorials with an Arduino/LED. I was following [this tutorial](https://programmingelectronics.com/tutorial-17-using-a-button-old-version/) when I ran into a problem.

I tried two configurations of the wires: one from the tutorial with a wire connecting from the 5V to the push button, and the other using a 330ohm resistor.

Just using a wire worked (see orange):

[image: Wired config]

Using a resistor to replace the orange wire did not work:

[image: Resistor config]

I'm confused about why using a resistor in place of the wire does not work. Could anyone explain the main differences between a resistor and a normal wire, and why it didn't work?

Comment: It looks like u have 2 resistors not one... and without a schematic... its hard to tell what you are asking.

Comment: Am I not supposed to have 2 resistors? The only change I made was the second resistor at the bottom, to replace the wire.

Comment: Lack of clarity. Without schematics of both configurations, we can't give an accurate answer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this, how do I make a schematic?

Comment: When you ask question, there is an option to add schematic. Using "Circuits lab". Simple web based software.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but you should also have a current-limiting resistor (330 Ohms would do) in series with the LED to limit the current through the LED.  The Arduino output may be damaged by excessive current without such a resistor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With two resistors you just have a voltage divider.

You should have it like one of these.. Pick one.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9KyHG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>